# How do you manage dependencies in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to be able to switch out my data layer in a React application during my test. In the Angular world this was easy I would do this...

```
class Repository{
  getData(){
     //use http and get some data
  }
}

class AngularController(Repository){
   var self = this;
   Repository.getData().then((objects) => {
      this.pageObjects = objects;
   })
}

//test
inject('check that controller sets data',(Repository, $controller) => {
    spyOn(Repository.getData).returns(fakeData);
    var controller = $controller('AngularController');
    expect(controller.data).toBe(fakeData);
})
```

But apparently in the React world it is functional and using IOC is bad and I 'should' be using modules instead of IOC, so I am wondering how do I do this in React?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sinon to stub and

```
import * as repo from 'repository';
```

to get object with all exported functions so I can stub them.

```
import sinon from 'sinon';
import ReactComponent from 'ReactComponent';
import * as repo from 'Repository';

sinon.stub(repo, 'getData', m => {
    return ["some", "data"];
});

describe('component stuff', () => {
  it('component fetching phase', () => {
    //not sure how you test your component rendering...
    //but you can use jest or enzyme
  });
});
```